# Websites or tools similar to Ginwiz (mobile website creator)

Tags: looking-for-a-script, website-design, mobile, software

I have a website which i want to make more mobile friendly(currently its not). While searching about this i found this awesome website [Ginwiz](http://www.ginwiz.com); my website can be modified into an mobile friendly site without any additional coding. But i find two disadvantages with this website (free version)

```
  1)We cant add our domain to it with out upgrading 
    (i dont have enough money to pay for it)
  2)We can only "Advanced edit" one page
```

Do you know any website which is similar to [Ginwiz](http://www.ginwiz.com) but can use our domain address instead of theirs (in free version). Do you have any idea about any tools which can be also used to convert my website to mobile website by trimming my current website easily.

Comment: Do you use a site based on any popular CMS? Or is it developed in-house?

Comment: i developed website myself in php,didnt used any cms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking the the best solution Ginwiz won't be able to help you on highly custom sites. The most controlled solution is that you write an alternative to your website. In most cases these sites are limited in function compared to the desktop version, and usually most of the code you've written to your site can be used with a few alterations.

Usually popular CMS systems include the option for a mobile optimised template, hence the question.

You basically have these options:

- Pay for Ginwiz
- Write a mobile site
- Alter CSS

If you decide to write a simplified mobile site I'd suggest using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) for cross browser compability, and for great features... It can really help with the development.

If you decide to alter the CSS of the page to accomodate mobile browsers you can use the following snippet to inlcude the css file for mobile:

```
<link href="style/style-small.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 986px)" />
<link href="style/style-normal.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 987px)" />
```

This actually tells the browsers to load style-mobile.css if the screen width is below 986px, and to load style-normal.css to load if the screen width is above 987px.

But keep in mind that using this will result in errors with unsupported browsers (Internet Explorer).